# QGIS 2.12.3 Crashes on intersecting two vector layers

Tags: qgis-2.12

I'm trying to intersect two vector layers (same projection, no spaces or unallowed characters in the filename) using intersect tool, but qgis crashes at every try. It says something like "created minidump in C:" and shows a path to a dmp-file. I already uninstalled Pisa (2.10 Version) and installed the Lyon-Version, but I still have the same problem. Can anybody give some hint to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you might need to show some of the dump file contents. No one could possibly help you based on the information provided.

Comment: @John: yes, I would like to. But The Dump Analysis says: 


On Thu 18.02.2016 14:16:49 GMT your computer crashed
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\qgis-20160218-151649-4124-12524-99ac688.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: Unknown () 
Bugcheck code: 0x0 (0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
Error: CUSTOM_ERROR
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. 
Google query: CUSTOM_ERROR

Comment: Try uninstalling QGIS, delete the `.qgis2` folder (in a path like `C:\Users\You\.qgis2`) and install it again. This helped me in the couple of times I received a crash-dump error.